# How long should thinset dry before gluing up tub surround?

Tags: shower, bathtub, adhesive, thinset

I replaced the walls in my bathroom and used concrete board around the shower. I plan on finishing the concrete board joints with the proper mesh tape and (premixed) thin-set as recommended but ...

I don't know how long I should let the joints dry before gluing up the tub surround.

Comment: Isn't it written on the side of the bucket of thin-set?

Comment: And if you add joints there with mesh tape and thin-set, won't it protrude too much that your wall will no longer be flat enough?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Feathering, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my main language, and I'm not familiar with the term "Feathering".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my experience, let it dry first - just as you would let joint comound dry...dry to the touch and firm.  I've pushed the envelope on a couple of occassions and what enbds up happening is the thinset shrinks as it dries, sucking the tile in, and causing a hairline crack.